# Service WAS was not found on computer '.'

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7

I am using Windows 7 Professional. When I am trying to start DefaultAppPool in IIS 7.0, I am getting error -

> Service WAS was not found on computer '.'.

Is there any changes in setting need to be done?

[image]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Well, start off by checking if it is installed.

[image]

Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Windows Process Activation Service

Comment: and then run **iisreset /restart** to make sure both services will run

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, I already had these enabled but was still getting the error.  I just disabled IIS features, restarted my pc, enabled them again, then restarted again and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 8):

Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off > Windows Process Activation Service > SELECT ALL > Click OK

Comment: This was the missing part for me. Thanks @Bopanna!